# Is it possible to have a print button link as the content of the mail

Tags: php, html, gmail, html-email

I don't know if this is a stupid question,sorry if it is but seriously I would like to know if it is possible to have a `print button` link inside my `mail` content,so that once i have clicked the `print link`,it would help me print the specific `mail content` without the `print button` being shown.I have used `window.print()` in an `html page` which allows me to print the specific contents of the page.Likewise,Is there some method by which i could `print` the mail contents.Hope someone could help me.

Comment: no, this is not possible.

Comment: tanx for the info @Dagon.. :)

Comment: In most cases, "Print" buttons on webpages display a different page altogether. Otherwise there would be no need for a Print button, and users could just do Ctrl+P. This is, of course, not possible in an email message, but you could think about having a "Print" _link,_ that points to a printer friendly webpage.

Answer (score 2):

To print specific content of an email you need to run javascript in your email and that script may have adverse effects in your email. some client sides respond email with js as spam and some will block that will create problem to you. So in my case better way is not to have print button in email.